# How to prevent execution of an event before until the last call is completed

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery event:

```
$('#button-next').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'index.php?route=product/category/display&cat=any&limit='+p+',1',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var text = data.output;
            goForward('scroller', text);
            p++;
        }
    });
});
```

That inserts a new item to the list and removes the last one. The problem is if the user starts clicking on the button so fast, it gets messed up. I need a way to prevent new calls before that last one is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to subscribe to the click action:

```
$('#button-next').one('click', process);
```

where you could define the `process` function like this:

```
function process() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'index.php',
        cache: false,
        data: { 
            route: 'product/category/display', 
            cat: 'any', 
            limit: p + ',1' 
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var text = data.output;
            goForward('scroller', text);
            p++;
            // we rebind the click event once again
            $('#button-next').one('click', process);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$('#button-next').click(function()` you can use `$('#button-next').one('click', function()`. This makes the unbind unneccessary and saves one line

Comment: @topek, excellent idea. I have updated my post to take your comment into account. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the button on click and enable it after ajax complete

```
            $('#button-next').bind('click', function() {
                $('#button-next').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: 'index.php?route=product/category/display&cat=any&limit='+p+',1',
                    cache: false,

                    success: function(data) {
                            $('#button-next').removeAttr('disabled')
                            var text = data.output;
                            goForward('scroller', text);
                            p++;
                    }
                });
            });
```